# When does a cast return a different pointer in case of single inheritance?

Tags: c++, pointers, inheritance, casting

> "This [...] demonstrates that a single object (e.g., an object of type Derived) might have more than one address (e.g., its address when pointed to by a Base* pointer and its address when pointed to by  a Derived* pointer). [...] In fact, when multiple inheritance is in use, it happens virtually all the time, but it can happen under single inheritance."
>
> Effective C++, Third Edition, Item 27, Scott Meyers.

Casting a pointer to a derived class to a pointer to a class higher in its class hierarchy possibly returning a different pointer value sounds logical in case of multiple inheritance.

But what situation would that happen in, in case of single inheritance ?

Edit - Are there cases aside from casting to a virtual base ?

Comment: Virtual inheritance, even when single.

Comment: Or simply an unconventional C++ implementation. There are many ways to implement vtables and not all of them leave the `this` pointer the same on each level of single inheritance.

Comment: Indeed. Thanks @SergeyA. Added "Are there cases aside from casting to a virtual base ?". If you don't see any, feel free to post your comment as answer.

Comment: @MaxLanghof Could you name such a unconventional implementation?

Comment: The fact that such an implementation is permitted to exist is sufficient!